# Proper command for Math equation

Tags: equations

Everyone, I am new to LaTeX, and I tried to learn to write Math equations. I use "\usepackage(mathtools}". I got some problem with "exponentiation", "sum", "integral", ... I want it to display like n=0 under the sum and so on. This is my command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
[...]
    $\left(A+B\right)\ket{\psi} = A\ket{\psi} + B\ket{\psi}$\\
    $AB\ket{\psi} = A\left(B\ket{\psi}\right)$\\
    $\exp{A} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{A^n}{n!}$
[...]
\end{document}
```

Could you help me?

[image: PDF output]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics) can be useful for you.

Comment: It sounds like you want display math (`\[ ... \]`) rather than inline math (`$ ... $`): is that correct?

Comment: These are a really useful advises. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer based on Joseph's advice:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ket}{\lvert}{\rangle}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  (A + B)\ket{\psi}
  &= A\ket{\psi} + B\ket{\psi}\\
  AB\ket{\psi}
  &= A(B\ket{\psi})\\
  \exp A
  &= \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{A^{n}}{n!}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

In case you also want to use `\bra`s and `\braket`s, you can use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\bra}{\langle}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ket}{\lvert}{\rangle}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\braket}[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1 \delimsize\vert #2}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \braket{A}{B}
  &= (\bra{A})(\ket{B})\\
  \exp A
  &= \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{A^{n}}{n!}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]